# Swash buckle creates time span class too in json file

Tags: c#, swashbuckle, asp.net-core-3.1

I use SwashBuckle with .net core 3.1 but when it creates the json settings it includes TimeSpan in Json and when create code with nswag studo it generate timespan class too. is it a bug or where I have done wrong. this is my code in start up:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "HR API", Version = "v1" });
        });
```

as I mentioned I use .net core 3.1 and swash buckle v5.3.3.
how can I escape and prevent it to generate time span class.
this is my property that needed:

```
public TimeSpan? StartTime {get; set;}
```

and this is the result that I take from nswag code generator:

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("dayStart", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; } = new TimeSpan();
```

and of course it generates timespan class too like this:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
public partial class TimeSpan
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("ticks", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public long Ticks { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("days", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public int Days { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("hours", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public int Hours { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("milliseconds", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public int Milliseconds { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("minutes", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public int Minutes { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("seconds", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public int Seconds { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("totalDays", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public double TotalDays { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("totalHours", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public double TotalHours { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("totalMilliseconds", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public double TotalMilliseconds { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("totalMinutes", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public double TotalMinutes { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("totalSeconds", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
    public double TotalSeconds { get; set; }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public static TimeSpan FromJson(string data)
    {
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TimeSpan>(data);
    }

}
```

and Json is like this:

```
"startTime": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/TimeSpan"
      },
```

but before updating to new version its json was like this:

```
"startTime":{"format":"time-span","type":"string"},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "json settings"? Are you talking about the API documentation generated as a JSON? And what do you mean by "TimeSpan" in the JSON? Did you mean timestamp? Can you add an example of the JSON where you have the problem?

Comment: in C# we have TimeSpan struct that represents time. it is a data struct like date time and it is not a class that I created it. it shouldn't create that class because C# has it on its own. in version 4.0.1 every thing was good. after update to last version it happened.

Comment: if you want I added my code and the code that has been generated as a example

Answer (score 3):

I'm using System.Text.Json rather than NewtonSoft. Inspired by Jafar's answer I was able to accomplish this by adding the following [MapType overrides](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#override-schema-for-specific-types) to the SwaggerGen config:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    ...
    // Make Swagger aware that we are using JsonTimeSpanConverter
    c.MapType<TimeSpan>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "0.00:00:00", Reference = null, Nullable = false });
    c.MapType<TimeSpan?>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "0.00:00:00", Reference = null, Nullable = true });
```

And then in my MVC initialisation I add the JsonTimeSpanConverter:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    // Accept/Export TimeSpans as strings (rather than array of properties)
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonTimeSpanConverter()));
```

Comment: Small additional hint: I found that setting `Format = "time-span"` and using `Example` for the showcase value (`new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string", Format = "time-span", Example = new OpenApiString("0.00:00:00") }`) allows C# client generator tools like NSwagStudio to create the client model with TimeSpan instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom Schema filter as Below:

```
public sealed class RequireValueTypePropertiesSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    private readonly CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver camelCaseContractResolver;
    public RequireValueTypePropertiesSchemaFilter(bool camelCasePropertyNames)
    {
        camelCaseContractResolver = camelCasePropertyNames ? new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() : null;
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema model, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        var ttt = context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Keys.Where(r => r.EndsWith("TimeSpan"));
        foreach (var item in ttt)
            context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove(item);

        foreach (var property in context.Type.GetProperties())
        {
            var schemaPropertyName = PropertyName(property);

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var value = model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value;
            }

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(TimeSpan?))
                if (model.Properties?.ContainsKey(schemaPropertyName) == true)
                {
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Format = "time-span";
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Reference = null;
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Nullable = true;
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Type = "string";
                }

            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(TimeSpan))
                if (model.Properties?.ContainsKey(schemaPropertyName) == true)
                {
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Format = "time-span";
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Reference = null;
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Nullable = false;
                    model.Properties.Single(a => a.Key == schemaPropertyName).Value.Type = "string";
                }

            if (model.Properties?.ContainsKey(schemaPropertyName) == true)
            {
                var propertyType = property.PropertyType;
                if (propertyType.IsValueType &&
                    !(propertyType.IsConstructedGenericType &&
                      propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                    if (!property.CustomAttributes.Any(attr =>
                    {
                        var t = attr.AttributeType;

                        return t == typeof(RequiredAttribute);
                    }))
                    {
                        if (model.Required == null)
                            model.Required = new HashSet<string>();

                        model.Required.Add(schemaPropertyName);
                    }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the JSON property name for <paramref name="property"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string PropertyName(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return camelCaseContractResolver?.GetResolvedPropertyName(property.Name) ?? property.Name;
    }
}
```

and I added in swagger configuration in startup like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "HR API", Version = "v1"});
            c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            c.DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase();
            c.SchemaFilter<RequireValueTypePropertiesSchemaFilter>(true);
        });
```